# Performance gain on checking changed data before UPDATE on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are doing quite a lot of insert/updates on a table on Azure SQL Server.

Is there any gain of loading some columns first (if update) and checking if they have changed compared to the stored data before doing an UPDATE?

To avoid logging, writing and index updates when the data is identical.

BTW: This is in a stored procedure, and the parameters (not shown here) are the new data.

Additional info: Most of the time there will be an UPDATE with no data changed because this is linked to a webhook which fire many times when the data we use is not changed. I would guess maybe 1 in 4-5 calls are with changed data.

'''

```
DECLARE @CurrentCustomerDisplayName nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CurrentCancelledAt datetimeoffset(7);
DECLARE @CurrentCustomerId bigint;
DECLARE @CurrentTrackingNo nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CurrentTags nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @CurrentToCountryCode nchar(2);


SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- First load the current row data from the table
    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @CurrentCustomerDisplayName = CustomerDisplayName,
        @CurrentCancelledAt = CancelledAt,
        @CurrentCustomerId = CustomerId,
        @CurrentTrackingNo = TrackingNo,
        @CurrentTags = Tags,
        @CurrentToCountryCode = ToCountryCode
    FROM dbo.Orders with (UPDLOCK)
    where  OrderId = @orderId;

    -- Check if exist
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Do insert
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Check if data has changed
        IF ((@CurrentCustomerDisplayName IS NULL AND @customerDisplayName IS NULL) OR (@CurrentCustomerDisplayName IS NOT NULL AND @customerDisplayName IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentCustomerDisplayName = @customerDisplayName))
            AND ((@CurrentCancelledAt IS NULL AND @cancelledAt IS NULL) OR (@CurrentCancelledAt IS NOT NULL AND @cancelledAt IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentCancelledAt = @cancelledAt))
            AND ((@CurrentCustomerId IS NULL AND @customerId IS NULL) OR (@CurrentCustomerId IS NOT NULL AND @customerId IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentCustomerId = @customerId))
            AND ((@CurrentTrackingNo IS NULL AND @trackingNo IS NULL) OR (@CurrentTrackingNo IS NOT NULL AND @trackingNo IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentTrackingNo = @trackingNo))
            AND ((@CurrentTags IS NULL AND @tags IS NULL) OR (@CurrentTags IS NOT NULL AND @tags IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentTags = @tags))
            AND ((@CurrentToCountryCode IS NULL AND @toCountryCode IS NULL) OR (@CurrentToCountryCode IS NOT NULL AND @toCountryCode IS NOT NULL AND @CurrentToCountryCode = @toCountryCode))
        BEGIN
            -- Do nothing, identical data
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Do UPDATE
        END
    END
COMMIT
```

'''

Comment: If we can assume (and I think we can) that OrderId is the primary key of Orders, then why do you need TOP 1? But I suggest you review the information in this [upsert discussion](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a primary key. So we dont need TOP 1. Is there any performance penalty for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a performance gain by not updating unnecessary rows, but you're likely going to lose out on this performance by splitting the process up into multiple statements.

With your current code, assuming most actions are either an insert or an update (with changes) you'll always execute at least two queries on the `Orders` table (Check + Upsert). You could start off with an insert and make this your check for if the row exists, that way if the required action is to insert, then you only require one query which will be more efficient than two. e.g.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT dbo.Orders (CustomerDisplayName, CancelledAt, CustomerId, TrackingNo, Tags, ToCountryCode)
SELECT  @CustomerDisplayName, @CancelledAt, @CustomerId, @TrackingNo, @Tags, @CurrentToCountryCode
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Orders WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE OrderId = @orderId)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE  dbo.Orders
    SET     CustomerDisplayName = @CustomerDisplayName,
            CancelledAt = @CancelledAt,
            CustomerId = @CustomerId,
            TrackingNo = @TrackingNo,
            Tags= @Tags,
            ToCountryCode = @ToCountryCode
    WHERE   OrderId = @orderId
    AND     NOT EXISTS 
            (   SELECT  CustomerDisplayName, CancelledAt, CustomerId, TrackingNo, Tags, ToCountryCode
                INTERSECT
                SELECT  @CustomerDisplayName, @CancelledAt, @CustomerId, @TrackingNo, @Tags, @CurrentToCountryCode
            );
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

A couple of references for the above that will provide a bit more reading. For the general `INSERT/UPDATE` pattern see [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) by Aaron Bertrand. For a bit more on the where clause above using `NOT EXISTS ( ... INTERSECT ...)` see the following article from Paul White: [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html). It is effectively the SQL-Server of the ANSI standard [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from).

As is often the case with performance based questions your mileage may vary. If 99% of your calls to the stored procedure are updates, then you may find that this is not the most efficient approach, and that doing the update before the insert is better (this is discussed in Aaron's article), or if most of those updates you may find that doing a check for changes first is the most efficient.

Comment: Good point, forgot about that. Should still use `XACT_ABORT` if you have an explicit transaction, or you could be left with a hanging transaction.

Comment: @GarethD As far as I can understand it will be minimum 1 query, and maximum 2. First one query to check existing data, and see if row already exists. If exist,, and nothing has changed, then no more queries. If row does not exist, then a INSERT statement, not UPDATE. And if row exists and data is changed, then an UPDATE query.

Comment: And BTW: Most of the time there will be an UPDATE with no data changed because this is linked to a webhook which fire many times when the data we use is not changed.

Comment: Yeah fair point, if most of the time the procedure runs there will be an update with no changes then your method may be faster. The question said that you were doing a lot of `inserts/updates` so my answer was based on that information. Ultimately assuming `OrderID` is a primary key the performance difference will probably be negligible anyway. If you really want to know which is going to be the best way, [why not race your horses?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)